# Add a number to unknown number in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Is it possible to add a number to a unknown number in sql column? For example:

In my sql database is a column named "overallRating". I want to add +1 to whatever number is stored in that column. So if number 14 is stored in overallRating column, +1 would make it 15.

Is this possible to do this without retreving this number from sql first? Something like:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET overallRating+=1 WHERE url='myurl..'
```

EDIT When solution was already given:

*Actually I haven't tried my code above, but I did now and it also works. I made a syntax error on my first try, that's why I thought it's not working.*

Comment: It should, does it give an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `+=` syntax is *very new* to T-SQL and generally not supported by most PROD systems today and so you just need to spell it out:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET overallRating=overallRating+1 WHERE ...
```

Comment: Sorry, our edits overlapped (I was just trying to fix a missing close quote). Rolled mine back.

Comment: @Jamiec, no worries at all. That's actually the first rollback I've ever performed, I welcome edits to my posts. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rootpanthera, I'm glad we could be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

It will work like

update users set userid = (userid + 1) where userid = 1